# Running FTP through Jenkins on windows server 2012

Tags: jenkins, ftp, windows-firewall

I have installed Jenkins in our server successfully, and we can run configure and run jobs.

I want to run a Windows Batch Command on a Jenkins job, that should download some files through FTP. Initially I had some issues with FTP as I was able to connect to the server, but couldn't download files or list them, as FTP was unable to establish a data channel because of the server's firewall configuration.

I was able to fix this issue, opening ports to the FTP executable, and I was finally able to download the files from command line.

Now I want to make the same operation I'm running on command line, but in a Jenkins job.

The problem is that once I try to make a wget or ls, the job stalls and nothing happens. **This behavior is similar to what I experienced in command line before opening ports**, but I can't tell if its the same issue as Jenkins is not giving any feedback (on command line I could see the line "150 File status okay; about to open data connection.", Jenkin's console is only displaying the commands sent with FTP, but not the FTP response).

I have tried applying the same firewall configuration as the one applied to the FTP executable, to the Jenkins executable and service. No go.

I also changed the user that launches the Jenkins service, so it is launched by an administrator account. But it's just not working.

Anyone has any idea of whats going on?

Comment: Do you need to with only batch script. you  can also try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485412/download-files-over-ftp-in-a-jenkins-job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "Execute Windows Batch Command", I executed the FTP command through a "Execute shell", and the process completes correctly.