# Downloading files from an FTP server in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to copy all the files from a specific folder on an FTP server. What is the best way to achieve it in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Because of development environment constraints, I use a unix expect script.

1. The file server is running an FTP service
2. A jenkins job runs a shell build step that runs an expect script, accepting 2 arguments the path for the required file(s) and a mask for the required file(s).
3. The expect script issues normal bash FTP commands e.g. `ftp -p 123.12.123.12` to start an FTP session, `binary` to change the transfer type,  `mget $filter` to get all files matching the filter and `bye` to end the FTP session.

Though also see this answer [download-files-over-ftp-in-a-jenkins-job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485412/download-files-over-ftp-in-a-jenkins-job)